# Animating with respect to speed

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation

How do you animate a UIImageView with respect to speed rather than duration. I have a bunch of UIImageViews in my app, and I want to move their centers from one point to the other. Since I'm animating them with respect to duration, they are not animating uniformly because of the differences in distance. It is very disorienting.

Comment: You may need to do it yourself with a CAKeyFrameAnimation, where you calculate out the distance per frame that each view can move and build out each animation frame based on that. You can have multiple CAKeyFrameAnimations (one for each view) be built by a single function... so this isn't too tedious of a solution. Then you just have to bundle all the animations together into a group and they'll all animate together. Also, setting it to use a linear timing function may help things look smoother between the views. I'd be happy to help you draft a solution if nobody has any better ideas. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Create an animation block and put all your `UIImageView's` within that block before calling `commitAnimations`.

```
- (IBAction)moveImageViews{
       [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
       self.firstImageToMove.frame = CGRectOffset(self.firstImageToMove.frame, 0, 50);
       self.anotherImageToMove.frame = CGRectOffset(self.anotherImageToMove.frame, 0, 50);
       [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```